# updating time in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

In my angularjs app, i define a var for put a "prefix" in my all console.log

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngResource', 'pascalprecht.translate']).run(function($rootScope, $timeout) {


    $rootScope.defineCLC = "[ZR Console CL] " + updatingTime() + " ===> ";

[etc ...]
```

I use $rootScope.defineCLC in my controllers.

For having the time updated, i put in pure js, outside :

```
function updatingTime() {
    setTimeout('updatingTime()', 3000);
    var currentTime = new Date();
    console.log('ok !');
    return currentTime;
}
```

problem is it's doesnt't work, the time is always the date when app whas executed :/ how to update the time for having it good in the console.log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout('updatingTime()', 3000);` will give you an error after 3secs (check the developer console in the browser) since you supply a string instead of a function.

You'll have to make a function and call it with angular's version of [setInterval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope, $interval) {
  var fun = function() {
    $rootScope.defineCLC = "[ZR Console CL] " + new Date() + " ===> ";
  };
  $interval(fun, 3000);
}]);
```